# Date in Textbox shows as text in Cell Range

Tags: excel, vba, date, textbox, userform

I have a userform set up for entering data, and one of the textboxes is coded to only accept dates in the format "dd/mm/yyyy". When this is submitted and entered into the database on excel, the date is entered in the format "mm/dd/yyyy", or as text if the entry cannot work within the "mm/dd/yyyy" format.

I am currently only using a simple bit of code to enter this information:

```
Sheet4.Range("M5") = TextBox2
Sheet4.Range("M5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Sheet4.Range("M5").Value
Sheet4.Range("M3").Select
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing to swap the date format round when it's entered to excel. It updates when I refresh the cell by double clicking into it and hitting enter, which what I tried to do with lines 2 - 4, but I can't seem to get it to work and display properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure the format of `ActiveCell` is the one you want, `dd/mm/yyyy`. Format is just a visual thing, but the value remains the same. Your textbox control may be in format `dd/mm/yyyy` but if the format of `ActiveCell` is different, you will see data in that format. But the value will be same in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is whatever you input in a TextBox is a string so when you input a date in TextBox, it is considered as a text string not a real date.

To deal with this, convert the date string in TextBox to the real date and then write it back to the cell.

Please try this...

```
Sheet4.Range("M5").Value = CDate(TextBox2)
```

Comment: Such an obvious answer that I was completely oblivious to! This works perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: @Merovin You're welcome! Glad it resolved your issue. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)